How to replace this corroded toilet flange?
I am replacing my toilet. I took it off and have encountered a rusted bolt circle. The bolt circle is flush with the tile and it can still accommodate screws. Additionally, there is a plastic flange sticking out but it doesn’t cover the bolt circle. Should I get a closet flange to bring it just above the floor so I can set the seal? Or should I just place a seal on the plastic piece set the toilet and call it a day?



It's a little unusual to have the top of the sanitary pipe that far above the flange. But if you raise the flange above the floor the toilet fixture may not seat properly and rock.
You should be able to install a regular seal. I'm assuming that's what you had there to begin with.
Since the toilet was rocking to begin with it was apparently high-centered on the sanitary pipe. So your thought to reduce the height of the pipe makes sense. Still, I would be cautious about mounting a second flange on top of the current one. You could end up with the same problem.
If the current flange is structurally sound and holds the bolts well I would go with it. If it isn't, then replace the flange.

So the toilet was rocking before I took it off. We had decided to just replace it because it was old. But I want to make sure the next one doesn’t rock. My thinking is remove the current sanitary pipe and install a lower flange on top of the metal flange that’s there just to have a clean lower surface to put the wax to.

Yes, reduce the height of the sanitary pipe but I'd be careful about raising the flange. See my revised answer given the new information you provided.
